# Can I avoid copying an unordered_map in C++ in the following situation?

Tags: c++, algorithm, memory, memory-management, unordered-map

### Context

I am trying to solve the Travelling Salesman Problem using a Dynamic Programming algorithm with C++. I am trying to solve the problem for 25 cities, meaning that I have to store up to **5 million key-value pairs** in a `unordered_map` **per iteration**.

Using this algorithm with Python and 4GB ram I had my process killed due to lack of memory, so I'm trying to improve the performance in memory.

### Problem

To reduce the amount of memory used, I am trying to keep two `unordered_set`, one with the values of the previous iteration, and another one with the new values.

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> costs;
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> new_costs;

for (int m = 1; m <= n; m++) {
  new_costs.clear();
  while (something) {
    // I build the content of new_costs based on the content of costs
  }

  // Here I want to make costs point to new_costs and free new_costs to
  // build the next iteration
  costs = new_costs; // ??
}
```

I don't know if I can avoid copying all `new_costs` to `costs` as we are talking about **millions** of elements.

I was wondering if I could use pointers to make `costs` point to `new_costs`, but in that case I don't know what would happen when I do `new_costs.clear();`.

### Question

Summing up my question is, how can I allocate new memory for `new_costs`, put the content of `new_costs` inside `costs` (hopefully in constant time?), and free the memory already used by the old `costs` that I will not use again?

Any help is really appreciated! Thanks!

-- Feel free to edit the title to make it more descriptive. I couldn't find a good title.

Comment: `std::swap` or `std::move` may help, if I understand the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best course of action is using standard functions. When you use std containers, using **std::move** or **std::swap** could be a good solution for your problem.

Comment: Thank you. **std::swap** is just what I was looking for :)

Comment: @dgrcode: I think `std::move` is what you're looking for. `costs = std::move(new_costs); new_costs.clear();` is an O(1) operation.

Comment: What would be the difference between using `std::move` vs `std::swap` plus clearing `new_costs`? Is it faster with move?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20807938/stdswap-vs-stdexchange-vs-swap-operator